# How to assign Roles to user in WPF

Tags: c#, .net

I am new to c#. I made application in which there are three tables : User, Roles and Assigned_Roles

```
 1. User Table column names:       
              user_id (PK)
              user_name(nvarchar(50))
              user_password(password)
 2. Roles Table Column names: 
              role_id(PK)
              role_name(nvarchar(50))
 3. Assigned_Roles
             assigned_id(PK)
             role_id(int)
             user_id
```

Each user has assigned right. I want that when user will log-in to application, things like dock-panel, system controls, creation of new task etc. should make available to view according to assigned roles to user.

I have no knowledge of how to do this. can anyone provide me some better solution or reading material?

Comment: This is too broad of a question. At a high-level, as far as WPF app is concerned your user role is just some property, and something (either a ViewModel or code-behind) has to tell the View which components to show/hide based on the role.

Comment: @NewDev can you please provide me any article or tutorial.

Comment: No, like I said, your question is too broad. Learn first how WPF works, how the View reflects your models and app state. There's nothing different about users/roles than any other app state.

Comment: I use a state instance which is registered with a life-time container and resolved each time a view model is created.  Inside the state instance is a class which defines the current user's permissions.

Comment: There is nothing WPF specific in your question, removed the tag...

Comment: Hi @GarryVass, Thank you for sharing! Exactly this is what i need, can you please provide me any article related to it Please. .... or should i have to make another Ticket to ask this question?

Comment: There's no article that I no of.  I have used this pattern for a long time because it fits well with Prism and Unity, but it was predicated upon an older pattern.  Most of the code is in proprietary custody, but I can provide a text description and some very minimal code if that's acceptable for your answer.  Just a few words to get you started if that's of any use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to solve this is to make `Roles Folder` like `Admin`, `User` etc. Then create `UserControls` according to each `Role` then simple call these like:

`<firstrole:UserControl1/>`